# Remove item in a many to many relation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot with spring data jpa and hibernate.

I have a many to many relation, but the releation join table has additional data

In my entity x

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "y")
private List<y> y;
```

In my entity y

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "z_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Z z;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "x_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private X x;
```

When i try to save x and i have remove all item of y, i set y to null.
but there is no delete who is done, only an update

Just want to delete y.

Comment: Do you want to delete y or y and z?

Comment: i updated, just want to delete y

Comment: Add orphanRemoval = true to you OneToMany. And don't set y to null. Instead, call y.clear().

Comment: @JBNizet Does this work despite the z entity still holds a reference to y?

Comment: @Tom y holds a reference to z, not vice-versa.